# Check if Java object is Collection, Array or String and empty

Tags: java, collections, instanceof, is-empty

I've got this method at the moment that I am trying to refactor.

```java
public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    boolean empty = false;
    if (value instanceof String && ((String) value).isEmpty()) {
        empty = true;
    } else if (value instanceof List && ((List<?>) value).isEmpty()) {
        empty = true;
    } else if (value instanceof String[] && ArrayUtils.isEmpty((String[]) value)) {
        empty = true;
    } else if (value == null) {
        empty = true;
    }

    return empty;
}
```

Is there an obviously better way to do this that I am missing?

I know I could put all the conditions on one `if` statement using chained `||` statements, but I don't really see how that is better than what I've got now.

Comment: for a list if (myList.isEmpty() ) instead of  if ( isEmpty(myList))

Comment: There isn't a significantly better way to do this.  Only minor tweaks.  Ultimately you need to do a sequence of tests.  But in Java 17 you will have the option of using `switch` expressions to do this; see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406

Comment: additionally to the answers below, the null check should be the first test, since if the value is null, no instanceof and cast is needed.

Comment: @juwil - I would leave that to the compiler.  There is an implicit null check in `instanceof` ... and the JIT optimizer is good at eliminating unnecessary (e.g. duplicate) null checks of all kinds.

Comment: The better approach is to redesign your application, removing the need for such a horrible method. Why do you need to handle entirely different objects with a single method? What does `ArrayUtils.isEmpty((String[]) value)` do? Is it equivalent to `((Object[])value).length==0`? Or does it something obscure? What about other array types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [deHaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68297607/5221149), the code can be improved by using `if-return` combinations.

You should however generalize your code a bit more, e.g. support all array types, not just string arrays, and support all collection types, not just lists.

Similarly, `String` implements an interface named `CharSequence`, so support that instead. That way the code will support classes like `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` too.

```java
public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    if (value == null)
        return true;
    if (value instanceof CharSequence) // String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer, ...
        return ((CharSequence) value).isEmpty();
    if (value instanceof Collection) // List, Set, Queue, Deque, ...
        return ((Collection<?>) value).isEmpty();
    if (value instanceof Map)
        return ((Map<?,?>) value).isEmpty();
    if (value.getClass().isArray()) // All array types
        return (Array.getLength(value) == 0);
    return false;
}
```

Code was modified to to use pure built-in methods, i.e. to not rely on `ArrayUtils`.

***UPDATED:** Added support for primitive arrays.*

The above implementation is a close match to the JSP EL `empty` operator:

> The `empty` operator is a prefix operator that can be used to determine if a value is null or empty.
>
> To evaluate `empty A`
>
> - If `A` is `null`, return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is the empty string, then return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty array, then return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty `Map`, return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty `Collection`, return `true`
> - Otherwise return `false`

Comment: Still doesn’t handle primitive arrays. Or `ByteBuffer`. Since this is an open end, generalizing the method is not going into the right direction. Rather, the OP should try to get rid of such a magic “empty, whatever that actually means” method. What about a class that implements `CharSequence` and `Collection` at the same time?

Comment: @Holger `ByteBuffer` doesn't have an `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, ideally I'd still like something cleaner, but for now this will suffice!

Comment: Well, I agree with Holger that the cleanest solution is to get rid of this strange concept of emptiness that means different things for different objects / values.  (Null and empty are not the same ...)

Comment: @Andreas right, currently `ByteBuffer` doesn’t have an `isEmpty()` method. Just like `CharSequence` hadn’t before Java 15. So is this method supposed to take the challenge of A) handle everything that conceptually contains elements or B) handle everything that currently has an `isEmpty()` method (to be adapted when changing)? If B then why does it handle arrays?

Comment: @Holger If you read the last part of the answer, we should be able to conclude that the method is supposed to mirror the JSP EL `empty` operator. Ok, so maybe I shouldn't have relaxed it to do `CharSequence` instead of `String`. ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

In Java 17, you will be able to write this using a `switch` expression.  According [issue 8213076](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213076), the syntax will be:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    return switch(value) {
      case String s -> s.isEmpty();
      case List l -> l.isEmpty();
      case String[] sa -> ArrayUtils.isEmpty(sa);
      default -> value == null;
    }
}
```

NB: This is a **preview** feature in Java 17.  It could change or even be removed entirely in a later release.

---

(The original proposed syntax in [JEP 406](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) was a bit different:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    return switch(value) {
      case String -> value.isEmpty();
      case List -> value.isEmpty();
      case String[] -> ArrayUtils.isEmpty(value);
      default -> value == null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the original version did not require a separate binding variable in each `case`.)

Comment: The syntax likely will be similar to the `instanceof` pattern matching of JDK 16. So you need a new identifier per case: `return switch(value) {  case String s -> s.isEmpty();  case List l -> l.isEmpty();  case String[] a -> ArrayUtils.isEmpty(a);  default -> value == null;  };`

Comment: The `instanceof` pattern matching would work as well, i.e. `return value instanceof String s? s.isEmpty(): value instanceof List l? l.isEmpty(): value instanceof String[] a? ArrayUtils.isEmpty(a): value == null;` does already work in JDK 16. When using `--enable-preview`, it will even work in JDK 14 and 15.

Comment: @Holger To amplify Holger's comment: a new binding variable is necessary for each case, shown in his example as `case String s -> s.isEmpty();`. The type of `value` doesn't shift around in different places as it does with, say, Kotlin's flow typing. Also note that switch patterns are a _preview_ feature in Java 17, so they are not intended for production use, and things may change in the future.

Comment: This will be super helpful once it's implemented in Java 17, but unfortunately I am locked in to Java 8 at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten this code by omitting the flag and directly returning the result of the checks for emptiness:

```java
public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        return ((String) value).isEmpty();
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
        return ((List<?>) value).isEmpty();
    } else if (value instanceof String[]) {
        return ArrayUtils.isEmpty((String[]) value);
    } else {
        return value == null;
    }
}
```

This could be considered an improvement of readability.

Comment: All `else`s could be removed and the last `if`could be replaced by `return value == null`

Comment: @khelwood totally right, the last one should be an `else` only and `return value == null` as the comment above states.

Comment: Or just `return value instanceof String? ((String) value).isEmpty(): value instanceof List? ((List<?>) value).isEmpty(): value instanceof String[]? ArrayUtils.isEmpty((String[])value): value == null;`

Comment: Yes this seems like a solid idea.

Answer (score 1):

Java native utils gives you the abaility to check if `Objects.isNull(value)` which is **not** equivalent to empty. If you want to stick with native Java you are doing it right just beautify your code and that's it.
However this method exists in springFramework `ObjectUtils` class regardless of the type of object :

```
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

public static boolean isEmpty(Object value) {
    boolean empty = false;
if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
empty= true
}
return empty;
}
```

Spring Framework doc : [Class ObjectUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.html)

Comment: This only applies to arrays of objects, not collections.